# Get Rows Where timestamp Column is 2 days Old

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

I have a table that has a column with the timestamp in sqlite3. It is default to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` such that when the row gets inserted, the current time is inserted. Now I am trying to fetch the rows that have been inserted 2 days ago or more. I wonder if that makes any sense.

Reading the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) I came up with:

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE timestamp < strftime('%s', '-2 days')`

but apparently that's wrong. I came up with this query because that is similar to the way in which I am doing the test in my actual code:

`strtotime($timestamp) < strtotime("-2 days")`.

But I was hoping that sqlite3 included some built-in checks for this type of situation.

Thanks, I appreciate any responses.

**EDIT**: Figured it out: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE timestamp < date('now', '-2 days')`

I'll keep this open in case someone can come up with something better.

Comment: Will do, didn't know that was proper etiquette :D EDIT: I'll accept it in two days, that's when the system will let me accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured it out, it works fine for me. I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but seems pretty straightforward and like I said, works:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE timestamp < date('now', '-2 days')
```

Comment: Does this account for different time-zones?

Answer (score 4):

In postgres (I know it is not your platform, but I am posting here for others' reference), you can also do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE my_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '2 DAY';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE timestamp <= datetime('now','-2 days')
```

where data format should be in one of following formats as mentioned in link

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html