# Removing rows from MySQL table where the timestamp is over one day old

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I found the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136674/get-rows-where-timestamp-column-is-2-days-old).

But it isn't working for me. I've modified it a bit, manipulated it, and I can't figure it out. I'm trying to remove rows that are over a day old. Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['prune'])) {

    $sql = "DELETE FROM logs WHERE time < date('now', '-1 days')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    
    echo 'Logs older than one day removed.';    

    }
```

In case it makes a difference, the column is a `TIMESTAMP` type.

### Edit

The question I linked to relates to SQLite3. So now my question is, how can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can subtract an interval:

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE time < now() - interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 9):

That answer was IIRC for SQLite3. You're using MySQL which does not support this syntax.

You want to use [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function (example below not tested but should work):

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE time < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-1,NOW());
```

Comment: Well that would explain the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, only the

`timestampadd`

in positive direction works when running through an asc ordered date calendar:

```
    if (urldecode ($aUrl['Select']) == '>')
        $this-> db-> where ('konzertdatum >', 'TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 1, "'.  $id . '") ', false) ;
    else 
        $this-> db-> where ('konzertdatum < ', 'TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -1, "'.  $id . '") ', false) ;
```

In negative direction (`-1)`, the timestamp goes back to the very first entry. I also tried not to use CodeIgniter, but the same consequence.

Summing up, `+1` as parameter for timestampadd works, `-1` works for the second lowest entry (then jumping back to the first one. But it fails when I step further away from the first date.

Comment: Programming life can be simple, I forgot the desc in the order to make the negative direction working, now it goes